# Basically live VJing in Blender - Triggering animations on the run

Tags: animation, particles, animation-nodes, nla-editor

We need to trigger an animation live, during a vj/theatre performance. The artist needs to easily start and stop a pre-made animation. I have been looking into Nonlinear Animation, but yet can not find what I'm looking for.

Is it possible natively in Blender? Let's say theres 20 particle systems waiting to be activated. With a click or two, one starts, then fades out, then another one starts when the actor is in position and with a click, it starts, etc.

Any help is very appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are you prepared to dive into python scripting, if necessary?

Comment: Yep. I am familiar with python. Just not with Blender Python that much. But I can handle it. I just need to toggle animation for some objects or collections and keep others on hold.

Comment: I might recommend using 2.79B instead of current blender, and using its game engine.

Comment: Isn't game engine deprecated? If so, not good move in the long run.